# How to triger a filter on a antd table with searchParams

Tags: reactjs, antd, urlsearchparams

I am using an **antd** table with a customized filter and I am trying to implement a new feature using URL search params to save time when sharing filtered results with colleagues, the idea is to share links.

The search params are being set on the URL after a filter, also I created a conditional in **componentDidMount** to check and get the search params and set the keyword on the in the component's state which I believe is what is required to trigger the filter on the table.
When pasting the URL on a new tab/browser, the component mounts with the desire state value but the filter doesn't kicks in.

Does anyone knows how to do it ? Any help is appreciated

[Demo_In_CodeSandbox_here](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-search-params-3ujnxe?file=/src/App.js:3031-3043) - takes a minute to load the table

I pasted the code below too.

```js
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./styles.css";
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: "",
    searchedColumn: ""
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() =>
            this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)
          }
          style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              this.setState({
                searchText: selectedKeys[0],
                searchedColumn: dataIndex
              });
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : "",
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: (text) =>
      this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ""}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      )
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    params.set(dataIndex, selectedKeys[0]);
    window.history.replaceState(
      {},
      "",
      `${window.location.pathname}?${params}`
    );

    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex
    });
  };

  handleReset = (clearFilters) => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: "" });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.search) {
      let arrParams = null;
      const getUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
      let params = new URLSearchParams(getUrl.search);

      for (let p of params) {
        arrParams = p;
      }

      console.log(arrParams);

      const [dataIndex, selectedKeys] = arrParams;
      this.setState({
        searchText: selectedKeys,
        searchedColumn: dataIndex
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        width: "30%",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("name")
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age",
        width: "20%",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("age")
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("address"),
        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
        sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"]
      }
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```